# PDF Find function does not work

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file and would like to perform the classic adobe find function (ctrl+f). My problem is that it turns out that it never finds any match whereas I can select the text and copy/paste it perfectly so I do not think it is a font encoding issue.

FYI it is a PDF I have downloaded from the internet(not created by myself) and when opening the document properties there is not a single description of it. The Document Restrictions Summary options are all set to "Allowed" except for Document Assembly, Page Extraction and Signing which are set to "Not Allowed".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: How can I upload it ?

Comment: Unless you created the PDF yourself (which you say you did not), or, alternatively, you wrote Adobe Acrobat Reader (which you probably did not), this question is off-topic for SO. ..That said: can you copy text out of this PDF into a plain text document? If not, the text is unreadable.

Comment: @ Jongware Yes I can copy it I already mentioned it. @mkl How can I share it

Comment: Use some file sharing mechanism without to many adds, upload it, post url here. Google drive or dropbox for example.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r3jv7lvx32q2ix/Joe%2014%20-%20Dependence%20Modeling%20with%20Copulas.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base issue is that the **Info** dictionary of the PDF is broken:

```
1270 0 obj<</Taylor and Francis()/CreationDate(D:20140519140437-07'00')/k¨¯©ßÄ8Ü¥[¦H-
×58O®¬tB!jŽi¿²©–ý³¿4)'Šóå:ÞcàG·Ñ•[H oÆv²O»Nj°=løvO+
`µÃrü}›y`,WÂ%Ü¿ d†/Title/Author(Joe, Harry)/Unknown/ModDate/Creator(TeX)/{¥¶¿‘É.’¶ZàQ'6XÎ/?Féû i
uŽp„¬L/Trapped/Keywords/PTEX#2eFullbanner/íŽ¿–Ê#ˆ¦”Qarmæ qq»ã
h
W<:Ê+Úã
¤ÑFÄ¦²¤.y.‹í¦TxÉ!©´‘Ê~s‹E;³/EBX#5fPUBLISHER/{úôêÎ™{Êçñ*yj
“kaî¼Y:/Producer>>endobj
```

It looks completely garbled.

I patched the file to have this object only contain an empty dictionary:

```
1270 0 obj<<>>endobj
nd Francis()/CreationDate(D:20140519140437-07'00')/k¨¯©ßÄ8Ü¥[¦H-
×58O®¬tB!jŽi¿²©–ý³¿4)'Šóå:ÞcàG·Ñ•[H oÆv²O»Nj°=løvO+
`µÃrü}›y`,WÂ%Ü¿ d†/Title/Author(Joe, Harry)/Unknown/ModDate/Creator(TeX)/{¥¶¿‘É.’¶ZàQ'6XÎ/?Féû i
uŽp„¬L/Trapped/Keywords/PTEX#2eFullbanner/íŽ¿–Ê#ˆ¦”Qarmæ qq»ã
h
W<:Ê+Úã
¤ÑFÄ¦²¤.y.‹í¦TxÉ!©´‘Ê~s‹E;³/EBX#5fPUBLISHER/{úôêÎ™{Êçñ*yj
“kaî¼Y:/Producer>>endobj
```

Now Adobe Reader allowed me to properly search the PDF.

It is funny to see such issues where a broken PDF allows much of the Adobe Reader code to work and causes only certain, seemingly unrelated, functionality to fail

Comment: If the rest of the PDF structure is correct, this *strongly* suggests some kind of bug in the software that created it. But .. without the `/Info` field we don't know what it was!

Comment: *If the rest of the PDF structure is correct* - at least iText successfully parses it after the patch (actually I initially tried to parse the original PDF text using iText and the resulting `InvalidPdfException` pointed me towards the broken **Info** indirect object). *bug in the software that created it* - which might also be a software which *manipulated* an intermediate PDF created by some other software.

Comment: Thank you mkl! However how can I apply this patch ? How do I access this info dictionary file ?

Comment: *how can I apply this patch* - I used a hex editor, searched for "Francis", and overwrote "/Taylor a" with ">>endobj" and a line break. You might want to inform the site from which you received that PDF that it is broken and ask for a repaired one...